# Control each button separately - jQuery

Tags: jquery, button

So I'm working on a project an it contains quite a lot of buttons, however is there a way in which when I mouse down on one button, it changes just the button I clicked. I know that I could just add a class to each button, but is there a more efficient way of doing it?

This is the current code which when you click on one button it changes them all.

```
$("button").mousedown(function() {
    $(".button").css("background","-webkit-linear-gradient(black, #333333)");
    $(".button").css("background","-o-linear-gradient(black, #333333)");
    $(".button").css("background","-moz-linear-gradient(black, #333333)");
    $(".button").css("background","linear-gradient(black, #333333)");
});
$("button").mouseup(function() {
    $(".button").css("background","-webkit-linear-gradient(#333333, black)");
    $(".button").css("background","-o-linear-gradient(#333333, black)");
    $(".button").css("background","-moz-linear-gradient(#333333, black)");
    $(".button").css("background","linear-gradient(#333333, black)");
});
```

For example if I had button named 1 could I set it so that the background changed without applying it to all the buttons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI you should put those styles in their own CSS classes and use `addClass` to change them. It will make your code much shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` as reference to the element being clicked and change that alone.

Example

```
$(".button").mouseup(function() {
    var elem = $(this); // elem contains the clicked element
    elem.css("background","-webkit-linear-gradient(#333333, black)");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as I'm new this has really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove classes with your gradients very easily with this code. It will also simplify your code. As well, you will keep all your CSS together;-)

```
$("button").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('gradient1').addClass('gradient2');
});

$("button").mouseup(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('gradient2').addClass('gradient1');
});
```